# How to merge Oracle SQL rows on NULL value

Tags: oracle

The result of my query (union of multiple selects) is a table with for example
the following data:

```
 A  | B  | C | D
----+----+---+---
 X1 | 1X |   |
 X1 | 1X | X |
 X1 | 1X |   | Y
 X2 | 2X |   | Z
 X2 | 2X |   |
 X3 | 3X |   |
 X3 | 3X | X |
 X4 | 4X |   |
```

Fields C and D contain NULL values if not holding value (X/Y/Z).
I want to merge the data in output on the first 2 columns as follows:

```
 A  | B  | C | D
----+----+---+---
 X1 | 1X | X | Y
 X2 | 2X |   | Z
 X3 | 3X | X |
 X4 | 4X |   |
```

How can I do that?

Comment: do you need those rows with null values? I mean, will you  aggregate those values or only select fields A, B, C and D?

Comment: You may be able to do it with a MERGE statement, and if not, then PL/SQL.

Comment: if this is the result of the union of some queries, you should consider reviewing those queries to produce a better result.

Answer (score 2):

If you only expect to have at most one value per row for fields C and D, then a simple `group by` should do the trick:

```
SELECT   a,
         b,
         MAX (c) AS c,
         MAX (d) AS d
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works but is ugly.  I will be interested in seeing a more elegant solution:

```
SQL> with tbl(id, cola, colb, colc, cold) as
  2  ( select 1, 'X1' , '1X' ,  NULL, null from dual
  3    union
  4   select 2, 'X1' , '1X' , 'X' , null from dual
  5     union
  6   select 3, 'X1' , '1X' , NULL , 'Y' from dual
  7    union
  8   select 4, 'X2' , '2X' , NULL , 'Z' from dual
  9    union
 10   select 5, 'X2' , '2X' , NULL ,NULL from dual
 11    union
 12   select 6, 'X3' , '3X' , NULL  ,NULL from dual
 13     union
 14   select 7, 'X3' , '3X' , 'X' ,NULL from dual
 15     union
 16   select 8, 'X4' , '4X' , NULL  ,NULL from dual
 17   )
 18   select distinct a.cola cola,
 19          a.colb colb,
 20          (select colc
 21           from tbl b
 22           where b.cola = a.cola
 23           and   b.colb = a.colb
 24           and b.colc is not null) colc,
 25           (select cold
 26           from tbl c
 27           where c.cola = a.cola
 28           and   c.colb = a.colb
 29           and c.cold is not null) cold
 30   from tbl a
 31  order by cola;
```

Output:

```
CO CO C C
-- -- - -
X1 1X X Y
X2 2X   Z
X3 3X X
X4 4X

SQL>
```